# How to use material design text fields in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mdc-components, swiftui-form

I want to use the Material Design text field component in SwiftUI. There is a Material Design Text Field Component written for UIKit but not one for SwiftUI. Is it possible to use this Material Design Text Field Component in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am concern its not possible to directly use material-design in SwiftUI. But you can integrate your UIKit view into your SwiftUI view(Do it with every view though its a bit tedious) and you can use material-design inside your SwiftUI view. Thats how I am using it now.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own textfield components with material-ui styled, and I find it easy using swiftui.

```
import SwiftUI 

struct CustomFieldText: View {
@Binding var name: String
var label: String
var required: Bool = true
var indicator: Bool = false
@State private var onKeyIn = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(label)
                if required {
                    Text("*")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .font(.custom("ZonaPro-SemiBold", size: self.onKeyIn || self.name != "" ? 14 : 18))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .offset(y: self.onKeyIn || self.name != "" ? -30 : 0)
            .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 1, blendDuration: 0))
            
            Rectangle().frame(height: 3)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8392156863, green: 0.8784313725, blue: 0.8784313725, alpha: 1)))
        }
        VStack {
            TextField(self.name, text: self.$name)
                .font(.custom("ZonaPro-SemiBold", size: 18))
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .textContentType(.nickname)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                .padding(.top, 5)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.onKeyIn = true
                }
            .zIndex(1)
        }
        
        VStack {
            if indicator && self.name.count > 0 {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Verifying")
                        .font(.custom("ZonaPro-Light", size: 10))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

and how to use it?

```
  CustomFieldText(name: self.$auth.email, label: "Your Email ID")
```